# Creating a grid in c

Tags: c, for-loop, grid, position

I need to create a 375 x 375 grid in c, and I need to create a grid of 25 (5x5) poles that will be spaced 75 (375/5) grid points apart. I will then need to calculate for any given grid point how close it is to a pole. This is not a visual grid, but I'm still having trouble wrapping my head on how to create this grid set-up programmatically. So far, I'v created a "Point" struct that consist of two ints x and y:

```
typedef struct{
    int x, y;
}Point;
```

I then define my grid as a 375x375 Point array and set the x and y values as`i` and `j`respectfully, in a nested for loop. However I'm having a hard time figuring out how to create the pole position array. Should it be a 5x5 array with the x and y values set as `i*15` and`j*15`? If so then how would I use the two 2D arrays together.I couldn't do a calculation like this obviously:

```
        for(i = 0; i < 375; i ++){
        for(j = 0; j<375; j++){
            distance(polePos[i][j], grid[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

but If I make it a 375x375 array, then how do I designate the pole position?
Am I on the right track? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you should temporarily forget about the grid and concentrate on a single point. Given a single point, how close is it to a pole?

Comment: Is this homework? Then please tag it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify at which column-/row-indices the poles should be placed so in the following i place them 75-apart starting at 0, so the poles are at column-/row-indices 0, 75, 150, 225, 300, 375 (so 6 poles). It might not be precisely what you had in mind but it will get you started.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "math.h"
double distance(double x, double y, double grid) {
    x = fmod(x, grid);
    y = fmod(y, grid); // <- these modulos makes us treat every interval like the interval 0...grid
    double dx = grid/2 - fabs(x -grid/2);
    double dy = grid/2 - fabs(y -grid/2);    
    //printf("%3u %3u %f %f \n", x, y, dx, dy);
    return sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
}
int main(void) {
    int i; int j;
    double grid[375][375];
      for(i = 0; i < 375; i ++){
        for(j = 0; j<375; j++){
            grid[i][j] = distance(i, j, 75);
            printf("%3u %3u %f\n", i, j, grid[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You neglected to point out that if you want to have a pole at position 375, you'll need a 376x376 grid.

Comment: @MrLister Yes there is no pole. Just the distances getting down to 1.0 of it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two grids `polePos[5][5]` and `grid[375][375]` of points you can compute the distances with the following algorithm:

```
double dist[375][375];

int pI = 0, pJ = 0;
for (int gI = 0; gI < 375; gI++) {
    while (pI + 1 < 5 &&
           abs(polePos[pI][pJ].x - grid[gI][0].x) >
           abs(polePos[pI + 1][pJ].x - grid[gI][0].x) {
        pI += 1;
    }

    for (int gJ = 0; gJ < 375; gJ++) {
        while (pJ + 1 < 5 &&
               abs(polePos[pI][pJ].y - grid[gI][gJ].y) >
               abs(polePos[pI][pJ + 1].y - grid[gI][gJ].y) {
            pJ += 1;
        }

        dist[gI][gJ] = distance(polePos[pI][pJ], grid[gI][gJ]);
    }

    pJ = 0;
}
```

There `pI` and `pJ` contain the nearest pole to the current grid point.

Answer (score 0):

If your *grid* and your *pole* are related, maybe it should be better to put them in the same structure.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
typedef struct{
    int x, y;
    bool pole;
} Point;
```

You can see it like a chess-board, which may have or have not a piece on each case.

You can after use naive or classical algorithms like [Dijkstra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), [Bellman-Ford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman-Ford_algorithm), [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-star_algorithm) in order to determine shortest path to one of your pole.